# C# app sending email from Outlook 365 account, error "5.7.57 Client not authenticated to send mail"

Tags: c#, email, outlook, smtp, office365

I have a C# application (.NET 4.8) that sends email from an Outlook 365 mailbox, and here is the code I'm using:

```
    var fromAddress = new MailAddress("sendingboxname@domain.com");
    var toAddress = new MailAddress("toaddress@domain.com");
    using (var smtp = new SmtpClient 
    { 
        Host = "smtp.office365.com", 
        Port = 587, 
        EnableSsl = true, 
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network, 
        UseDefaultCredentials = false, 
        Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("sendingboxname@domain.com", "pword") 
    }) 
    { 
        using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress) { Subject = subject, Body = body, IsBodyHtml = true }) 
        { 
            smtp.Send(message); 
        } 
    };
```

I am getting the following error:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 'The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 Client not authenticated to send mail. Error: 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the request did not meet the criteria to be authenticated successfully. Contact your administrator. [MN2PR14CA0001.namprd14.prod.outlook.com 2024-01-31T14:51:46.902Z 08DC224A19943AD3]'

- SMTP is turned on for the sending email account.
- Two Factor Authentication is turned "off" for the sending email account.
- I have triple-checked the email/password - I can login to outlook.office.com with the credentials I'm using.
- The Microsoft Outlook 365 Support team could not resolve this problem.

However, I believe that Microsoft is still trying to "two factor" the account when my program tries to send mail from the account.

To make matters more interesting, I have another Outlook 365 account, with all the above settings configured the same way, and my program can send from that account.  My theory is that this long-standing account was somehow unaffected by security changes Microsoft has made recently.  I have only been trying to send recently from the problematic account.

Comment: This is a common misunderstanding. `EnableSsl` doesn't just mean "enable encryption". It means "use SSL instead of TLS". The [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl?view=net-8.0#remarks) explain it, albeit a bit circuitously. See the "An alternate connection method..." paragraph. It talks about SMTP/SSL and port 465. You're using port 587 so you should be using TLS instead.

Comment: "*The Microsoft Outlook 365 Support team could not resolve this problem.*" Are you sure about that? Or were you just asking a tier 1 Outlook support person for help with C# integration code that needs a developer to assist with?

Comment: @madreflection I tried each of the following (individual tests):  1) Port=465, EnableSsl=true;  2) Port=587, EnableSsl=false;   Neither of these tests worked.   Also, note that with another account and my original program code, it works and has worked for years.

Comment: @TylerH I insisted that they escalate it - said they did, and finally told me this:  "I have been able to work with the team and confirmed everything worked correctly with the product. However, the issue lies with the application used.  I will be closing this ticket."   So that's where they left it after over 2 weeks of back and forth with the support team.  I showed them that it worked with another account, and they even created another account and it wouldn't work with that account either.  Something has changed with authentication of accounts.

Comment: You may try to enable network tracing. See [Network Tracing in the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/network-tracing) to see if it gives any additional information.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [How to set up a multifunction device or application to send emails using Microsoft 365 or Office 365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365) and [Enable or disable authenticated client SMTP submission (SMTP AUTH) in Exchange Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/authenticated-client-smtp-submission)

Comment: Do you have _any_ conditional access policies in your AAD environment? If so, you may need to manually/explicitly exclude this user from them, even if the user does not otherwise qualify for them. FWIW, this error code and explanation have been around since they moved to enforcing modern auth, so it's not likely anything new on Microsoft's part.